# Get weather info without gps

Tags: java, android, gps

I can't have the weather info withot gps.. The code to find my location and weather is this:

```
private boolean isRuntimePostGingerbread() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }

    public void loadWeathercard() {
        //Set the date
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        citylb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.citybox);
        //Check if the custom weather place preference is enabled
        if (!sharedPrefs.getBoolean("weather_customlocationcheck", false)) {
            citylb.setText(getString(R.string.rilevamento));

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            /**
             * Check the provider exists before registering for updates from it
             * */
            if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, this);

            if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, this);
            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } else {
            //Get the custom city, refresh the city label and get the weather
            citylb.setText(sharedPrefs.getString("weather_customlocation", getString(R.string.location_null)));
            getWeather((String) citylb.getText());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if the device is online
     */
    /**
    *   Default method
    */ 

    public Boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()){
            return true;
        // This is method suggested.. Have i use this?
        }
        return false;
    }  
    private void getWeather(String location) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            Log.d("YWeatherGetter4a", "onCreate");
            YahooWeatherUtils yahooWeatherUtils = YahooWeatherUtils.getInstance();
            yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), location, this); // Basta mettere la location presa dalle preferences
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no connection available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    /**
     * Rilevo la posizione attuale
     * */

    public void gotWeatherInfo(final WeatherInfo weatherInfo) {
        if (weatherInfo != null) {
            current = weatherInfo.getCurrentText().toString();
            // Converto in stringa la temperatura
            TempCurrent = String.valueOf(weatherInfo.getCurrentTempC());
            String TempHigh = String.valueOf(weatherInfo.getForecast1TempHighC());
            String TempLow = String.valueOf(weatherInfo.getForecast1TempLowC());
          //  + weatherInfo.getAtmosphereHumidity() + "%"  per l'umidit
          /* LoadWebImagesTask task = new LoadWebImagesTask();
           task.execute(

                    weatherInfo.getCurrentConditionIconURL()
            );*/
           Time oggi = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
           oggi.setToNow();
            String orariometeo = oggi.format("%k:%M");

           ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview_forecast_info);
           if(current.toLowerCase().contains("sunny")){
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.sunny);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("partly cloudy")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.partlycloudy);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.partlycloudy);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("mostly cloudy")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.cloudy);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mostlycloudy);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("fair")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.fair);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("showers")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.showers);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("foggy")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.foggy);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mist);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("thunderstorms")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.thunderstorms);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("thundershowers")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.thundershowers);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.storm);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("freezingdrizzle") || current.toLowerCase().contains("hail")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.freezingdrizzle);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.freezingdrizzle);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("lightsnowshowers")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.lightsnowshowers);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chanceofsnow);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("clear") || current.toLowerCase().contains("hot")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.clear);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("cloudy")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.cloudy);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudy);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("snow")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.snow);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snow);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("drizzle")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.drizzle);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lightrain);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           } else if (current.toLowerCase().contains("rain") || current.toLowerCase().contains("showers")) {
               current = getResources().getString(R.string.showers);
               Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

           }

           temperaturenow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperaturenow);
           temperaturenow.setText(current + " ");

           temperatura = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
           temperatura.setText(TempCurrent + "°");

           maxmin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maxmin);
           maxmin.setText(Html.fromHtml(TempHigh + "/" +"<small>"+TempLow+"</small>" +"°C"));

           imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view){
                   boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather");  
                    if(installed) {
                        String meteoinfo = weatherInfo.getWeatherurl();
                        //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
                        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather");
                        LaunchIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, meteoinfo);
                        startActivity(LaunchIntent);    

                    } else {
                       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(weatherInfo.getWeatherurl()));
                       startActivity(i);
                    }
               }
           });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no result returned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    class LoadWebImagesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap[]> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap[] res = new Bitmap[6];
            res[0] = ImageUtils.getBitmapFromWeb(params[0]);

            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] results) {
            super.onPostExecute(results);
            citylb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), results[0]));

        }

    }


    public void loadWeathercard1() {
        //Set the date
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        citylbpref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityboxpref);
        //Check if the custom weather place preference is enabled

            //Get the custom city, refresh the city label and get the weather
            citylbpref.setText(sharedPrefs.getString("weather_customlocation", getString(R.string.location_null)));
            getWeather1((String) citylbpref.getText());

    }

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Address> addresses = null;
         if (arg0 != null){
                double longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
                double latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

             try {
                 addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 Log.e("MyTag", "MyMessage", e); // use this instead e.printStackTrace();
             }

             if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){
                 citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());

                 getWeather((String) citylb.getText());
             }else{
                 citylb.setText(getString(R.string.location_null));
             }
                 //citylb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.citybox);


                //if (addresses.size() > 0) return addresses.get(0).getLocality();
         }

    }
```

Now, what i need it's have a "manual" location.. I tried to change the "loation" here:

```
yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), location, this);
```

using a string like:

```
yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), "New York", this);
```

but doesn't work... any idea?

Comment: #1, put your location provider checks in the order in which you would like to get them (GPS first, then NETWORK, for example) and stop checking when it's satisfied. #2 - define "doesn't work"

Comment: It returns "Error no location found". Can you show me what you exactly mean?

Comment: Note too that you have far too much information in your post - only post the parts that are relevant.

Comment: I posted everything because I don't know exactly which part of code has to change..don't care about the image that I change..just need how set a location to see its weather info using this code. I know for sure that "location" parameter is a string I pass that I take from gps and actually goes well..but now I don't want find the weather using gps. Understand me?

Comment: I actually think a better title is get location without a gps.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for YahooWeatherUtils, I found http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbdbbda0ae4ff7532748f/com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient?tag=dragonfly

Their suggestion is:

```
Location location = locationClient.getLastLocation();

YahooWeatherUtils ywu = YahooWeatherUtils.getInstance();
if PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean("weatherUseCurrentLocation", true) && location != null) {
   ywu.queryYahooWeather(getActivity(), location , this);
} else { 
   String city = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("weatherCity", "Vancouver Canada");
   ywu.queryYahooWeather(getActivity(), city , this);
}
```

So, it seems that the function `queryYahooWeather` can get lat/long or city name.  You just need enough information for city name.

Comment: Ok but in my case where have I to put the info? Like city, temperatura, maxmin etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Googleplay services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) you can get your location without a GPS.  It seems to default to sources such as cell towers and known wifi locations.  Bonus if the device actually has a gps and the gps is turned on google play services will use it but it won't do the annoying please turn on gps so this will work perfectly fine for your application. The first fix is really fast too.

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements

         GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
         {

...

    if (locationManager == null) {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
                }




     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
         * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
         * location or start periodic updates
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
            if (action_track) {
                if (mLocationRequest == null) {
                    // Create a new global location parameters object
                    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                    // Set the update interval
                    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
                    // Use high accuracy
                    mLocationRequest
                            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
                    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
                }
                mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                stopLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
```

and magically the location comes into this method.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
```